# MIDL compile error: enum with "cy"

Tags: c++, idl, midl

I have a simple IDL file which contains only one `enum`. One of the identifiers is `cy`.

```
[
  uuid(2642345F-F2AB-3600-8926-26E823800902),
  version(1.0),
]

library MyLib
{
    typedef[ uuid(a0b0aa7b-345f-4b3a-b88f-d6cdd048e205) ]
    enum Codes
    {
       cy, 
       abc
    } Codes;
};
```

However, MIDL won't compile this and gives me an error like:

> MIDL2025: expecting an identifier near "cy"

My first guess was that `cy` is a keyword/reserved word in MIDL -- but it's not.
My second guess was that either `cy` has already been used somewhere or is a type -- but it's not.

Any idea on what could be the issue here?

Comment: You cannot put an enum inside the library {} block. Just move it outside of it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on some experimentation, it appears that the compiler is denying case insensitive names from WTypes.h.

For example, it will also deny these names:

```
byte_blob
bstr
clipdata
decimal
userbitmap
userhbitmap
remhglobal
statflag
...etc...
```

Comment: But the enum in my code is in a different library (MyLib). So why should it conflict with those in Wtypes.h ?

Answer (score 0):

The *first* step is to investigate whether the is a problem *specifically* with `cy` or whether it's something else.

For a start, I'd change it to `cyxyzzy` or `zx` and see if it still complains. If so, there's probably something wrong with the *structure* of the name (such as being all lower case). If not, it's probably something to do with the specific `cy` identifier.

Another possibility is swapping around the `abc` and `cy` lines to see if the error follows the `cy`.

One thing you may want to consider, there are quite a few hits when searching for `midl cy` on the net that seem to suggest `cy` is aliased to a `currency` data type so that *may* be an issue.

The changes I've suggested above should hopefully confirm or deny that possibility but, at a bare minimum, they will help in deciding the scope of the problem.